# select case and error join multiple table

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim strSQL As String


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsearch.Click
    Dim fieldselect As String = ""

    Select Case ComboBox1.Text
        Case "startYear"
            fieldselect = "startYear"
        Case "genres"
            fieldselect = "genres"
        Case "Rating"
            fieldselect = "Rating"
    End Select


    conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Movies.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;")

    strSQL = "SELECT startYear, genres, averageRating FROM (basic.tconst Inner JOIN Rating.tconst on basic.tconst=Rating.tconst)" & fieldselect & "'" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"

    conn.Open()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)

    Dim ds As New DataSet("Movies")

    da.Fill(ds, "Movies")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Movies")
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Print out strSQL and it'll tell you what is wrong with the query. If you aren't sure, execute the output on the database directly.

Comment: Please add context and format the code properly so we'll be able to help

Comment: What is your question?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Keep you data objects local so you can control there closing and disposing. Using...End Using blocks do this for you even it there is an error.

Are all your fields in the Select Case the same datatype? If not you will have to adjust the code. If you need help, tell me the datatypes so I can fix the code.

Always use parameters to avoid sql injection. A text box can hold a Drop Table command. Parameters are treated as values not executable code.

If you need to update later in the code, you will need to have a primary key available in your Select.

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Since your field name exactly matches the combo text the Case statement is not necessary
    Dim fieldselect As String = ComboBox1.Text
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Movies.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;")
        Dim strSQL = "SELECT startYear, genres, averageRating FROM basic.tconst Inner JOIN Rating.tconst on basic.tconst=Rating.tconst Where " & fieldselect & " = @FieldValue;"
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FieldValue", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            conn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: all the field are the same datatype. And i can't use primary key because of the requirement, is there any way that doesn't use primary key to code ?\

Comment: I am referring to Update and Delete commands. If there is no way to uniquely identify which record to act on the database cannot complete the action. If you can provide enough information in the Where clause to identify the record it could work but if not it will act on every record with that criteria.

Answer (score 0):

i wanted to use combo box as the filter for my program, i need to filter data from 2 different table. rating has it own table and basic is different table. both of the field mention above does not have any connection.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit had to help without context but I gave it a try :

I would replace 
`strSQL = "SELECT startYear, genres, averageRating FROM (basic.tconst Inner JOIN Rating.tconst on basic.tconst=Rating.tconst)" & fieldselect & "'" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"`

With

```vb
"SELECT startYear, genres, averageRating " &
"FROM basic.tconst " &
"INNER JOIN Rating.tconst on basic.tconst=Rating.tconst " & fieldselect & "'" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```

To get better help, could you explain how tables Rating and basic works and what fieldselect is ?

Comment: You might want to fix the rest of it, this has more errors than just the join.

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I don't understand much of his situation, without context

Comment: Understood, but even without context, the structure of the SELECT statement is missing an important keyword and operator.

Comment: Yep, the `WHERE`, considering he put `"'%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'` I would even say   `"WHERE X LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"`But I wouldn't just put that randomly somewhere in the request

Comment: This answer uses string concatenation in building the query.  This is wide open to SQL Injection hacks.  I realize that you were just suggesting changes to the OP code, but in my opinion, answers should not promote dangerous coding habits.  At the very least, you should at least mention that issue.

Comment: I was ... Unaware of that. If you have time to educate me and OP on the subject that would be really nice of you, cause I have no ID how to write it otherwise :/

Comment: @Thryn, there are more in-depth examples, but here is a link to [sql injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Further down that link are examples of using parameterized statements.